# PHP передает в атрибут тега массив в виде строки, как его передать в переменную js в виде массива?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Допустим

```
тег a href="#" data-attribute="[1980, 2], [1990, 3], [2000, 4], [2010, 90], [2014, 1600]"
```

Как jquery значение атрибута перевести из строки в массив?

**Обновление**

```
var str = '['+attribute+']';
var arr = JSON.parse(str);

var data = $(this).attr('data-attribute');
        var str = '['+data+']';
        var arr = JSON.parse(str);
        console.log(arr);
```

Выдает

> [Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]

Answer (score 1):

Если делать плохо, то можно так:

```
var str = "[1980, 2], [1990, 3], [2000, 4], [2010, 90], [2014, 1600]" // надеюсь вы знаете как получить значение атрибута.
var arr = eval('['+str+']');
```

Использовать eval плохо. Уже лучше:

```
var str = '['+attribute+']';
var arr = JSON.parse(str);
```

Во втором решении мы делаем из обычной строки строку, какую можно рассматривать как JSON

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: Если есть возможность модифицировать вывод, то добавление этих двух скобок на сервере (создание валидного JSON) многократно упрощает задачу:

   // пусть $elem - уже выбранный с помощью jQuery элемент
   $elem.data('attribute');
   // [Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось! :)

Comment: @pain-x01, а вы что хотели? Консоль вам и говорит что arr это массив, состоящий из массивов.

Comment: да, все правильно, спасибо!)